# PowerPoint’s "Save as Picture" adds unwanted space to resulting image

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, shapes

When I right-click a textbox shape and select "Save as Picture", no matter what format I choose, the resulting image has unwanted space in it.

For example, if I have a textbox shape with text "Label", font "Arial", font size 8 and a red border, when I save this shape (PNG or GIF or EMF or whatever) the resulting image has some space to the left, top and right of the red border. It seems as if the textbox was centered in the image. Is there a way to get rid of this space?

**EDIT:**

Hi, I've found an answer on [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-powerpoint/save-as-picture-adds-unwanted-space-to-resulting/b5b8e7e9-d515-49f2-923d-845a441e69fa). Not the answer I would have liked, but an answer after all

Thanks again

Comment: What version of PowerPoint are you using?

Comment: You can auto crop it using third party software. [See this for example](http://superuser.com/questions/812784/how-to-automatically-crop-a-roughly-uniform-background-from-a-series-of-images/827094#827094)

Answer (score 3):

The text is adding padding beyond the shape.  If you select your shape with text, then paste as a picture, then crop this picture to the borders of the shape, then save that edited image, you will not get the additional gaps.  Or you can paste the text as a picture and crop it to fit inside your shape; and then save this new combined image as a picture.  Either way, you will get rid of the extra padding.